# Failure in DataFlow that isn't present in DirectRunner assert isinstance(value, bytes), (value, type(value)) related to processing GroupByValues

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm reading from a Json file then grouping by a key and then applying a function to the list in Dataflow.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
def calculate_precision_recall(p_label_collection, label, true_col, pred_col, score_col):
    label_collection = list(p_label_collection) # Explicit casting for running on Dataflow as opposed to DirectRunner
    y_true = np.array(map(lambda row: row[true_col] == label, label_collection)) # Boolean Array False -> 0, True -> 1
    y_score = np.array(map(lambda row: 0 if row[pred_col] != label else row[score_col], label_collection))
    if (y_true.sum() == 0):
        # In the one off chance that there are no true labels we get NaNs in the
        # scitkitlearn recall calculation
        return [], [], []
    else:
        prec, rec, thresh = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_score)
        return (prec.tolist(), rec.tolist(), thresh.tolist())



output = (pipeline | 'ReadText' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('$FILE_NAME')
                   | 'RowToJson' >> beam.Map(lambda txt: json.loads(txt))
                   | 'GetKey' >> beam.Map(lambda row: (row[$KEY], row)
                   | 'GroupyBy' >> beam.GroupByKey()
                   | 'ProcessGroup' >> beam.Map(lambda (key, group): (key, calculate_precision_recall(p_label_collection=group, label=key, true_col="foo", pred_col="bar", pred_col="pred_foo", score_col="score_bar")))
```

This all works well and fine in Direct Runner, but when I move to Dataflow I get the following error. $KEY, $FUN etc. are just place markers btw.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 582, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 166, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 49, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:3605)
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 50, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:3509)
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 65, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:3424)
    with self.shuffle_source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 69, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:3368)
    self.output(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 154, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:5783)
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 86, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:3622)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 233, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:8582)
    self.output(wvalue.with_value((k, wvalue.value)))
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 154, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:5783)
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 86, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:3622)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 339, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:11089)
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 340, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:11043)
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 382, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive (apache_beam/runners/common.c:10156)
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 390, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:10458)
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 431, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented (apache_beam/runners/common.c:11673)
    raise new_exn, None, original_traceback
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 388, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:10371)
    self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 189, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:6270)
    self.output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 480, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs (apache_beam/runners/common.c:12500)
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 84, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:3588)
    self.update_counters_start(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 90, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.update_counters_start (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:3808)
    self.opcounter.update_from(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 62, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.update_from (apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.c:2396)
    self.do_sample(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 80, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.do_sample (apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.c:3017)
    self.coder_impl.get_estimated_size_and_observables(windowed_value))
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 730, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables (apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.c:22968)
    def get_estimated_size_and_observables(self, value, nested=False):
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 739, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables (apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.c:22687)
    self._value_coder.get_estimated_size_and_observables(
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 517, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.AbstractComponentCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables (apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.c:18394)
    c.get_estimated_size_and_observables(
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 99, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables (apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.c:4264)
    return self.estimate_size(value, nested), []
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 75, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CoderImpl.estimate_size (apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.c:3733)
    return self._get_nested_size(len(self.encode(value)), nested)
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 345, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.BytesCoderImpl.encode (apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.c:11771)
    assert isinstance(value, bytes), (value, type(value))
RuntimeError: AssertionError: (u'$KEY', <type 'unicode'>) [while running 'ProcessGroup']
```

It seems to be trying to ?encode? my group as a unicode string and that there is no problem with my keys.

Comment: Can you share more details on what $FUN may be?  It looks like you may need to add a type annotation to the ProcessGroup step (see https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-type-safety/).  Beam tries to infer this based on the function, but you may be hitting a case where this isn't working properly, so it would be helpful to see more details of what $FUN really is.

Comment: @CharlesChen I tried beam.GroupByKey().with_output_types(Tuple[str, Iterable[Dict[str, Any]]]), but I got UserWarning: Using fallback coder for typehint: Dict[str, Any]. which seems to mean that it will use the pickleCoder and it wasn't really doing anything. I have not tried using type hints on the function. I'll do that now.

Comment: The underlying issue seems to be that you can't use the "str" type hint for this data, since the data is of type "unicode".  Can you try replacing "str" with "unicode" in the type hint?

Comment: @CharlesChen now I'm getting "Using fallback coder for typehint: Dict[unicode, Any]." Any example of my dictionary is {'a': 'a', 'b': 5.0}. I'll try changing the Dict[unicode, Any] to Dict[str, Any] and Dict[Any, Any]

Comment: @CharlesChen it seems like a previous version of this code that was extremely similar is now also failing with the <type unicode> output when it was previously working on March 13th.

Comment: Neither Dict[str, Any] nor Dict[Any, Any] worked

Comment: Can you provide the code for $FUN?  It looks like the error is happening with the output of ProcessGroup / $FUN.

Comment: @CharlesChen I've added the function

Comment: @CharlesChen what is the serialization library actually used in dataflow (vs. direct runner)? Is there a way I can test serialization locally? It is frustrating to have to start up dataflow over and over again and see all these errors.